# An vector with different "names" in the same vectorial space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\beta=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\space $,$\space \phi=\{(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)\} \space$ and $\space \omega=\{(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)\} \space$ be basis of $\mathbb {R^3}$. Let $u$ be a vector of $\mathbb {R^3}$ such that $[u]_{\beta}=(2,-5,7)$.

$\beta, \phi$and $\omega$ are basis of the same vectorial space, hence they span the same set of vectors.
To rewrite $u$ in $\phi$, I followed two different paths. First I wrote $u$ as a linear combination of the vectors of $\omega$ and then I wrote $[u]_{\omega}$ as a linear combination of $\phi$ vectors, as follow:

$[u]_{\beta}=(2,-5,7)=\omega_{1}(1,1,1)+ \omega_{2}(0,1,1)+\omega_{3}(0,0,1)$

By solving a linear system, one obtain,$\space \omega_{1}=2$,$\space \omega_{2}=-7$,$\space \omega_{3}=12$. So $[u]_{\omega}=(2,-7,12)$.

Repeting the same process to get $[u]_{\omega}$ as a linear combination of $\phi$ vectors, one obtain $[u]_{\phi}=(\frac{3}{2},\frac{21}{2},-\frac{17}{2})$

Then I wrote $u=(2,-5,7)$ in the basis $\phi$, as follow:

$(2,-5,7)=\phi_{1}(0,1,1)+\phi_{2}(1,0,1)+\phi_{3}(1,1,0)$

Solving again a linear system, one gets $[u]_{\phi}=(0,7,-5)$.

Surprisingly, I didn't get the same coordenates of $u$ in the basis $\phi$. Is there any theorem that justify this?

And, is correct to say that the same $u$ vector has different "names" in the same vectorial space? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to have $\phi$ and $\omega$ be identical sets, and therefore presumably the same basis?  We say that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space with *basis* $\beta$ (or other linearly independent spanning set), and if the elements of $\beta$ are *ordered*, then we speak of *representing* a vector by its coordinates with respect to that ordered basis.

Comment: No, my mistake.I will correct jus now

Comment: It was my mistake on copying from paper.Now its all right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is wrong because you first must find out how to "translate" $\,\omega-$ coordinates into $\,\phi-$ coordinates.

With the usual basis in $\,\Bbb R^3\,$ , the vector $\,u_\beta=(2,-5,7)\,$ is simply multiplying by $\,4\,$ the first element of the basis $\,\beta\,$ , by $\,-5\,$ the second one and  etc.

As you found, $\,u_\omega=(2,-7,12)\,$ , which means *the scalation* on the corresponding basis vector changed. Geometrically (or, if you prefer, "geograhically"), $\,u_\beta\,,\,u_\omega\,$ are in the very exact point ("place") on the real space, but the way to describe that site changed.

In order to change $\,\omega\,$ by $\,\phi\,$ you have to know how to pass from one to the other one, and not to assume the scalation is the same as with the usual, natural basis $\,\beta\,$, and for this you have to describe the vectors of $\,\omega\,$ in function of the ones in $\,\phi\,$:

$$\begin{align*}(1,1,1)&=\frac{1}{2}(0,1,1)+\frac{1}{2}(1,0,1)+\frac{1}{2}(1,1,0)\\{}\\{}\\(0,1,1)&=1\cdot(0,1,1)+0\cdot(1,0,1)+0(1,1,0)\\{}\\(0,0,1)&=\frac{1}{2}(0,1,1)+\frac{1}{2}(1,0,1)-\frac{1}{2}(1,1,0)\end{align*}$$

Thus, and indexing the elements in$\,\phi\,$ as $\,a_1,a_2,a_3\,$ for simplicity:

$$u_\omega=(2,-7,12)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_1+ a_2+a_3)\right)-7(a_1)+12\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2-a_3)\right)=$$

$$=(1-7+6)a_1+(1+6)a_2+(1-6)a_3=(0,7,-5)=u_\phi$$

The above nightmare is one of the best reasons I know to motivate students to study *matrices*...

Answer (score 0):

No. You did something wrong. In particular, in

> Repeting the same process to get $[u]_\omega$ as a linear combination of $\phi$ vectors

you evidently tried to solve

$$ (2,-7,12) = \phi_1 (0,1,1) + \phi_2 (1,0,1) + \phi_3(1,1,0) $$

which is nonsensical! The expression of the vectors of the system $\phi$ are given in standard coordinates. So you are equating apples (an expression in $\omega$ coordinates) to oranges (an expression in $\beta$, that is to say standard, coordinates).

You need to first solve for the system $\phi$ in terms of $\omega$, that is to say, writing $v_1 = (0,1,1)_\beta$, $v_2 = (1,0,1)_\beta$ and $v_3 = (1,1,0)_\beta$ so that the system $\phi = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, you need to find $[v_1]_\omega$ and $[v_2]_\omega$ and $[v_3]_\omega$ first, before you can try to solve

$$ (2,-7,12) = [u]_\omega = \phi_1 [v_1]_\omega + \phi_2 [v_2]_\omega + \phi_3[v_3]_\omega $$

You will find then this will give you the same values $\phi_{1,2,3}$ as solving

$$ (2,-5,7) = [u]_\beta = \phi_1 (0,1,1) + \phi_2 (1,0,1) + \phi_3 (1,1,0) = \phi_1 [v_1]_\beta + \phi_2 [v_2]_\beta + \phi_3 [v_3]_\beta $$

Comment: Thanks both for the help, after I thought a bit (with more paper and pencil)I realized that the $3$ different basis spans the same vectorial space, and $u$ (that is a vector of the previous vectorial space) can be writeen as a linear combination of each of the previous basis.So each linear combination of $u$ have to be equal. If, in the beguining it's given the coordinates of $u$ in some of the $3$ basis, I just need to find the coefficients of the other linear combinations in terms of what I have.